# How to fix XSS in rails

Tags: xss, encoding, rails

I am able to inject `` javascript:alert `1` `` or `javascript:alert(1)` into the `href` field of the rails app and it is getting executed as JavaScript. Html encoding is already implemented but it doesnt encode brackets and back quotes.

How to solve this? What is the best method to prevent XSS in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should always validate user input.**

For example, since you're expecting an URL, you could check that the submitted string starts with `http://` or `https://`.

```
submitted_url.start_with?('http://', 'https://')
```

Comment: That sounds like a hack right? Is there a module in Rails to output encode these kind of strings?

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus: I'm not a Ruby developer so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this in Ruby / Rails, but the main idea still stands: you need to validate that the submitted URL is a valid URL! Encoding the output isn't enough.

Comment: The fix is deployed as you have mentioned. Thanks :)